# Contents overflow in Drupal Dynamic Display Block

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal

[On this website](http://www.justfemme.in/), the dynamic display block (with images and contents) it repeats twice in in Mozilla and Chrome. But in IE, it completely flows above its boundaries covering the logo. 
Please tell me how to go about it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, I got this error:

```
~Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Fri, 22 Apr 2011 07:21:21 UTC


Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 47
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://www.justfemme.in/sites/all/themes/drupalmagazine/js/DD_belatedPNG.js?e
```

this is a problem with that particular file (Javascript)

It's probably better to contact the author of the file (its written on the top of the file).

you can try to add this to your style.css file, line 222

overflow: hidden;

so that block would be...

```
#top {
overflow: hidden;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D8F3C9;
border: 1px solid #1D94A6;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
width: 946px;
```

}

Comment: That helped and i am no more getting the overflow problem. But when I click on those thumbnails, they dont show up the respective article. Any further help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: do they link to the wrong article? or they simply won't link to anything? I can't check because I only have Internet Explorer 9 and with it, the scroller works as expected.